# powershell を使って　Import-Module virtualenvwrapper の実行

Tags: python, powershell

poewrshellを使って、Data Visualizationを学びはじめた者です。
Pythonのversionは2.7
windowsは8.1を使用しています。

私の、システム環境変数パスは、下記の通りです。

```
c:\python27\;c:\python27\scripts;c:\python27\tools\scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio 2010\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

現在、基本的に（http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows）のガイダンスに沿って、コンピューター環境を整えている状態です。
powershell, python, git, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper-powershellのインストールは（助けてもらいながら）順調に進んだのですが、
type:`Import-Module virtualenvwrapper` という所でスタックしてしまいました。。（virtualenvwrapper-powershellのインストールは完了しています。。）

私が、`Import-Module virtualenvwrapper`と入力すると、以下のエラーメッセージが得られます。

```
PS C:\python27> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
Import-Module : The specified module 'virtualenvwrapper' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

また、モジュールを、そのモジュールと同じ名前のフォルダに保存するか、.psm1をコマンドに使うと上手くいくかもしれないよ。とのご指摘を頂き、((https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096527/import-module-virtualenvwrapper/31097136#31097136))

```
C:\Python27\virtualenvwrapper
```

に`virtualenvwrapper.psm1`を配置し、
`Import-Module virtualenvwrapper`を実行してみましたが、エラーメッセージは上記と同じでした。。

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'virtualenvwrapper' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

また、`Import-Module virtualenvwrapper.psm1`も実行してみましたが、以下のエラーメッセージが得られました。。。

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'virtualenvwrapper.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in
any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module virtualenvwrapper.psm1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

また、 `Import-Module C:\Python27\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1`　も実行してみましたが、以下のエラーメッセージが得られました。。。

```
PS C:\python27>  Import-Module C:\Python27\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1
Import-Module : The specified module 'C:\Python27\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1' was not loaded because no
valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:2
+  Import-Module C:\Python27\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Python27\vir...envwrapper.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

また、このページを参考に（https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035903/installing-virtualenvwrapper-powershell-in-windows-8-1-import-module-failing）、
`WindowsPowerShell\Modules` というフォルダーをドキュメントに作成し、（the virtualenvwrapper-powershell bitbucket ）からとってきた、`VirtualEnvWrapper` ディレクトリを
Modulesフォルダに設置し、`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`　を実行してから`Import-Module virtualenvwrapper`を実行したのですが、やはりエラーとなりました。。

エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

```
PS C:\python27> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
PS C:\python27> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
Import-Module : The specified module 'virtualenvwrapper' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

長々と申し訳ございませんでした。
どなたか、何かアイデアのございます方、お力を貸して頂けますと助かります。。

★追記★
BLUEPIXY様へ、下記新たなエラーメッセージとなります。。

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run
C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:48 char:3
+ if [ "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON" = "" ]
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:48 char:5
+ if [ "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON" = "" ]
+     ~
Missing type name after '['.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:54 char:3
+ if [ "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV" = "" ]
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:54 char:5
+ if [ "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV" = "" ]
+     ~
Missing type name after '['.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:59 char:38
+ virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home() {
+                                      ~
An expression was expected after '('.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:64 char:7
+     if [ "$workon_home_dir" = "" ]
+       ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:64 char:9
+     if [ "$workon_home_dir" = "" ]
+         ~
Missing type name after '['.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:71 char:7
+     if echo "$workon_home_dir" | (unset GREP_OPTIONS; \grep '^[^/~]' > /dev/null ...
+       ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:71 char:53
+     if echo "$workon_home_dir" | (unset GREP_OPTIONS; \grep '^[^/~]' > /dev/null ...
+                                                     ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:71 char:34
+     if echo "$workon_home_dir" | (unset GREP_OPTIONS; \grep '^[^/~]' > /dev/null ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisInIfStatement

Import-Module : The specified module 'virtualenvwrapper' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

★追追記★

以下が、新しいエラーメッセージとなります。。
だいぶエラーメッセージが、短くなりました！！

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run
C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r
Switch-DefaultPython : The term 'Switch-DefaultPython' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:16 char:1
+ Switch-DefaultPython
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Switch-DefaultPython:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Initialize : The term 'Initialize' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:334 char:1
+ Initialize
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

★追追追記★

下記、エラーメッセージ
メッセージがら見るに、いろんなものが自動化されていないようですね。。

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run
C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Win\Win.psm1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r
Initialize : The term 'Initialize' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1:334 char:1
+ Initialize
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Initialize:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

★＠追記★
遂に成功したかのように見えます。以下のメッセージの様に、今回のエラーは、『TabExpansion』によるものだけで、これは無視してよいエラーみたいです！
ということは、今回の”Import-Module virtualenvwrapper”の実行は、成功かと思います。
しかし、メッセージ中に、何も『成功』形跡がありません。。
これは本当に成功したのでしょうか。。

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\support.psm1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\win.psm1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run
C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\VirtualenvWrapperTabExpansion.psm1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'Function:\TabExpansion' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\VirtualenvWrapperTabExpansion.psm1:12
char:21
+ $_oldTabExpansion = Get-Content Function:TabExpansion
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Function:\TabExpansion:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand


Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run
C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\virtualenvwrapper.psm1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run
C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\Extensions\Extension.Project.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run
C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\Extensions\Extension.UserScripts.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): r
PS C:\windows\system32>
```

また、`Get-Command *virtualenv*`

を実行すると、下記の様に表示され、やはり成功したかのように見えます。

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-Command *virtualenv*

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           cdvirtualenv ->                                    VirtualEnvWrapper
Alias           cpvirtualenv ->                                    VirtualEnvWrapper
Alias           lsvirtualenv ->                                    VirtualEnvWrapper
Alias           mkvirtualenv ->                                    VirtualEnvWrapper
Alias           rmvirtualenv ->                                    VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        add_posh_to_virtualenv                             VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        add2virtualenv                                     VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        CDIntoVirtualEnvironment                           VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        Copy-VirtualEnvironment                            VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        GetVirtualEnvCompletions                           VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        GetVirtualEnvData                                  VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        Get-VirtualEnvironment                             VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        LetVirtualEnvsThru                                 VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        LooksLikeAVirtualEnv                               VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        NewVirtualEnvData                                  VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        New-VirtualEnvironment                             VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        Remove-VirtualEnvironment                          VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        Set-VirtualEnvironment                             VirtualEnvWrapper
Function        showvirtualenv                                     VirtualEnvWrapper
Application     add2virtualenv.bat
Application     cdvirtualenv.bat
Application     lsvirtualenv.bat
Application     mkvirtualenv.bat
Application     rmvirtualenv.bat
Application     virtualenv.exe
Application     virtualenv-3.4.exe
Application     virtualenv-clone.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

モジュールを置く場所はモジュールパスで示される場所になければいけません。
標準のスクリプトモジュールのユーザーレベル(ユーザー毎のモジュール)パスは
`C:\Users\UserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`
です。(UserNameは、それぞれのユーザー名）
そういう意味で、モジュールを置く正しいディレクトリは最後のやつです。
つまりドキュメントフォルダにWindowsPowerShell\Modulesフォルダを作り
Modulesフォルダにモジュール名のフォルダ`virtualenvwrapper.psm1`の場合は`virtualenvwrapper`フォルダを作りそこに`virtualenvwrapper.psm1`ファイルを置きます。
それで、
`Import-Module virtualenvwrapper`を実行すればいいかと思います。
(バージョン３以降は起動時に自動読込されるはず）

Comment: BLUEPIXY様。
ご回答ありがとうございます。
”C:\Users\SomaSoma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper”　に、”virtualenvwrapper.psm1”を設置し、”Import-Module virtualenvwrapper”を実行してみましたが、再びエラーが発生しました。。
以下、エラーメッセージです。。

Comment: PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
Import-Module : The specified module 'virtualenvwrapper' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (virtualenvwrapper:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: こちらでは、同様の手順でモジュールのインポートができます。エラーメッセージでは指定されたファイルが見つからないということなので、何らかの勘違いかミスがあるものと思われます。試しに別の`.psm1`ファイルとそれ用のディレクトリを作成してみてはどうでしょうか？ また、ドキュメントフォルダの移動などはしてないですよね？

Comment: エラーメッセージからは、virtualenvwrapperフォルダにvir‌​tualenvwrapper.psm1ファイルが`存在しない`と思われます。実は`vir‌​tualenvwrapper.psm1.txt`だったりフォルダだったりしませんよね？その.psm1ファイルはテキストエディタなどで開けますか？

Comment: BLUEPIXY様。
只今、テキストエディタで、”virtualenvwrapper.psm1”を開いてみたところ、
notepadの淵の部分には、”virtualenvwrapper.psm1 - Notepad”　と表示されています。。

Comment: 本当に素人なもので、申し訳ありません。。
ドキュメントフォルダの移動に関してなのですが、ドキュメントフォルダは、元々、どこにあればよろしいのでしょうか？
おそらく移動していないと思うのですが、間違えて、過去に移動している可能性も0%ではありません。。

Comment: 実行ユーザー（つまりログインユーザー）は、`SomaSoma`なんですよね？今言ってるパスはユーザーパスなので、他のユーザーからは使えません。PowerShellを特別なことをしないで起動してテストしてみて下さい。

Comment: Type of file が　SH File (.sh)　　となっていました！！しかしこのファイル種類をどう変更するのでしょうか。。

Comment: powershellのテストとは！？何をすればよろしいのでしょうか？。。

Comment: notepad で、virtualenvwrapper.psm1と表示されていたのなら問題ないような気がしますが`Type of file が　SH File (.sh)` は、どこで確認されたのですか？私はwindows7 なので表示が異なるのかもしれないですが・。つまり拡張子が`.sh`だと言うことですか？ テストはImport-Module を試してみることを言ってます。

Comment: つまり、virtualenvwrapper.psm1.shになっていたということだと思います。。
只今、ファイル名をvirtualenvwrapper.psm1に変更し、”Import-Module virtualenvwrapper”を実行したところ、違うエラーが発生しました。。
質問のところに追記します。

Comment: ちなみに、テスト結果は以下のようになりました。

PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module

cmdlet Import-Module at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name[0]:

Comment: リンク先のガイダンスを見てみたんですが、`virtualenvwrapper.sh` は、CentOS 用のファイルでPowerShell用のスクリプトではないと思います。
ガイダンスを見てみると特別`virtualenvwrapper.psm1`を作成する手順はないようなので、インストールの部分で自動的に作成されるものと思います。つまりは、インストールの部分で何らかの失敗があって、`virtualenvwrapper.psm1`がちゃんと作成されなかったんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: BLUEPIXY様！
virtualenvwrapper-powershellを、インストールし直し、(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096527/import-module-virtualenvwrapper/31097136#31097136)からとってきた、psm1ファイルを消去して、公式サイトから（https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/12.7.8）psm1ファイルを引っ張ってきました。

しかしまたまた、エラーが発生しました。。しかし、エラーメッセージが短くなった所から、着実にゴールに近づいている気がします！

Comment: 私のpythonのバージョンは2.7.5で、アップデートの仕方がわからず、このままにしているのですが、もしかするとpythonのアップデートが関係していたりしますでしょうか。。？

Comment: pythonアップデートしてみましたが、同じエラーでした。。

Comment: `Switch-DefaultPython` というコマンドを実行しようとしたが実行できなかったというエラーです。これは、`Win.psm1`で定義されているようですから先にこちらのモジュールを使えるようにしておく必要があるように思います。しかし、これらの手順は本来自動化されてるはずなのでは？？

Comment: 昨日、ずっとこのエラーについて調べていたら、時々、バグで自動化されてないものがある、と書いてあるものを読んだ気がします。。Win.psm1のモジュールを使えるようにするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。。

Comment: 回答した手順と同じくModulesディレクトリにWinフォルダを作ってそこにWin.psm1をコピー Import-Module Win の実行という手順でいいかと思います。

Comment: 上記、ステップ完了しました！！
ですが、また（ある意味面白い）エラーメッセージが得られました。。
質問に追追追記します。。ｗ

Comment: `Initialize` は、`Support.psm1` で定義されているコマンドの様です。 １つ釘を刺しておきたいんですが、本来自動でセットアップされるべき事柄を手動でこのようにしてやっていけるとは限りません。（私自身もお付き合いしきれません）

Comment: おっしゃる通りですね。。
自動でセットアップできる方法を模索してみます。。
ありがとう御座います！

Comment: `setup.py`が失敗した上でのことですよね？

Comment: はい！！そうなります！！。。、

Comment: お！遂にSupport.psm1 　を入れるとうまくいったように見えます！
質問欄に追記しておきます！